# clang++: candidate function [with Callable_T = void (int, double), Args_T = <int, double>] not viable: expects an rvalue for 3rd argument

Tags: c++, clang, pack, rvalue

I have a test framework where I need to capture the call to a generic function (a test suite) and execute it at a later time.

For this I use a class template with a parameter pack and I store the arguments in a tuple.

Everything builds and runs fine with GCC 10 and GCC 11, but fails with clang.

The code looks like this:

```cpp
  template <typename Callable_T, typename... Args_T>
  class test_suite : public test_suite_base
  {
  public:
    test_suite (const char* name, Callable_T&& callable,
                Args_T&&... arguments);

    virtual ~test_suite () override;

    virtual void
    run (void) override;

  protected:
    Callable_T&& callable_;
    std::tuple<Args_T...> arguments_;
  };

  template <typename Callable_T, typename... Args_T>
  test_suite<Callable_T, Args_T...>::test_suite (const char* name,
                                                 Callable_T&& callable,
                                                 Args_T&&... arguments)
      : test_suite_base{ name }, callable_{ std::forward<Callable_T> (
                                     callable) },
        arguments_{ std::forward<Args_T> (arguments)... }
  {
    runner.register_test_suite (this);
  }

  template <typename Callable_T, typename... Args_T>
  test_suite<Callable_T, Args_T...>::~test_suite ()
  {
  }

  template <typename Callable_T, typename... Args_T>
  void
  test_suite<Callable_T, Args_T...>::run (void)
  {
    current_test_suite = this;

    begin_test_suite ();
    std::apply (callable_, arguments_);
    end_test_suite ();
  }
```

The full code is available from [GitHub](https://github.com/micro-os-plus/micro-test-plus-xpack/blob/xpack-develop/include/micro-os-plus/test-suite.h).

The class is instantiated with:

```cpp
static void
ts_args (int iv, double fv)
{
  using namespace micro_os_plus::micro_test_plus;

  test_case ("args", [&] {
    expect (eq (iv, 42)) << "iv is 42";
    expect (eq (fv, 42.0)) << "fv is 42.0";
  });
}

static micro_os_plus::micro_test_plus::test_suite ts_3
    = { "Args const", ts_args, 42, 42.0 };

static int n = 42;
static micro_os_plus::micro_test_plus::test_suite ts_4
    = { "Args vars", ts_args, n, 42.0 };
```

The first call (using constants) is fine; the second call (with a variable) fails with:

```
/Users/ilg/My Files/WKS Projects/micro-os-plus.github/xPacks/micro-test-plus-xpack.git/tests/src/sample-test.cpp:320:51: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'test_suite'
static micro_os_plus::micro_test_plus::test_suite ts_4
                                                  ^
/Users/ilg/My Files/WKS Projects/micro-os-plus.github/xPacks/micro-test-plus-xpack.git/include/micro-os-plus/test-suite.h:204:5: note: candidate function [with Callable_T = void (int, double), Args_T = <int, double>] not viable: expects an rvalue for 3rd argument
    test_suite (const char* name, Callable_T&& callable,
    ^
/Users/ilg/My Files/WKS Projects/micro-os-plus.github/xPacks/micro-test-plus-xpack.git/include/micro-os-plus/test-suite.h:201:9: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
  class test_suite : public test_suite_base
```

I also tried to use explicit types with `test_suite<void (int, double), int, double>`, but it did not help.

So things are more complicated than I thought, and it seems that with this syntax **only** rvalues are expected to match (although GCC is less strict).

To recap, the question is how to capture a generic call with variable arguments (which in my case happens during test suite auto-registration, via static constructors), store everything and execute it at a later moment (when the test suite is executed part of the test).

Comment: Your constructor accepts only rvalues (`&&`), so Clang is correct. I am surprised that you managed to get the other compilers to compile it. In my test they all produce similar errors as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/qe9M5a8ve

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test. The full source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/micro-os-plus/micro-test-plus-xpack/blob/xpack-develop/include/micro-os-plus/test-suite.h. Is there any solution to adjust the code to accept both constants and variables in the same call?

Comment: I am sure there is a duplicate question here somewhere, but I couldn't find one right now. In short: You need to make the constructor a template and use the constructor's template parameters instead to get forwarding references. Then you'll also need to add a deduction guide because the implicit one won't work anymore.

Comment: Before making `test_suite` a class template, I tried with a constructor template, but I could not use a tuple as member in the class, since its type was not known at that level. I tried creating a lambda in the constructor, to capture the values, but it had different problems.

Comment: You need template parameters on the class as well as on the constructor and a deduction guide to deduce the class template arguments from the constructor template arguments. I don't have time to write a full answer.

Comment: A solution that passed my tests was to make only the constructor template, and use std::bind() to create the callable.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that passed my tests was to make only the constructor a template, and store the deferred call as a function created with `std::bind()`:

```cpp
  class test_suite : public test_suite_base
  {
  public:
    template <typename Callable_T, typename... Args_T>
    test_suite (const char* name, Callable_T&& callable,
                Args_T&&... arguments);

    // The rule of five.
    test_suite (const test_suite&) = delete;
    test_suite (test_suite&&) = delete;
    test_suite&
    operator= (const test_suite&)
        = delete;
    test_suite&
    operator= (test_suite&&)
        = delete;

    virtual ~test_suite () override;

    virtual void
    run (void) override;

  protected:
    std::function<void (void)> callable_;
  };

  template <typename Callable_T, typename... Args_T>
  test_suite::test_suite (const char* name, Callable_T&& callable,
                          Args_T&&... arguments)
      : test_suite_base{ name }, callable_{ std::bind (callable,
                                                       arguments...) }
  {
    runner.register_test_suite (this);
  }

  void
  test_suite::run (void)
  {
    // Run the test suite function prepared with std::bin();
    callable_ ();
  }

  test_suite::~test_suite ()
  {
  }
```

The parameter pack is correctly captured and allows constants, variable, references and pointers:

```cpp
static void
test_suite_args (int ic, int iv, int& ir, int* ip1, int* ip2)
{
  using namespace micro_os_plus::micro_test_plus;

  test_case ("args", [&] {
    expect (eq (ic, 42)) << "ic is 42";
    expect (eq (iv, 43)) << "iv is 43";
    expect (eq (ir, 44)) << "ir is 44";
    expect (eq (*ip1, 45)) << "*ip1 is 45";
    expect (eq (*ip2, 46)) << "*ip2 is 46";
  });
}

static int in = 43;
static int in44 = 44;
static int& ir = in44;
static int in45 = 45;
static int in46 = 46;
static int* ip2 = &in46;

static micro_os_plus::micro_test_plus::test_suite ts_args
    = { "Args", test_suite_args, 42, in, ir, &in45, ip2 };
```